# Why do these two derivations of the variance of a binomial random variable give different answers?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I am learning AP Statistics, and I have come across the derivation for the variance of a binomial random variable.

The derivation goes something like this:
Suppose you have a binomial random variable $X$ with the probability of success $p$. Then write $X=Y + Y + Y + ... + Y=nY$ as the sum of $n$ Bernoulli random variables $Y$ with probability of success $p$. Then, the variance is $\sigma^2_x = \sigma^2_Y + \sigma^2_Y + ... + \sigma^2_Y = n\sigma^2_Y = np(1-p)$ which gives the correct answer. However, shouldn't it also be possible to do $\sigma^2_x = \sigma^2_{nY} = n^2\sigma^2_Y = n^2p(1-p)$? Why does this give a different (and incorrect) answer?

Comment: If you write $X=nY$, $X$ can only takes value $0$ or $n$, this is clearly not a binomial. In this case, there is no independence between the different bernoulli trials. Therefore summing the variances is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context ($X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$) it is essentially **wrong** to write: $$X=Y+Y+\cdots+Y\tag1$$

This should be:$$X=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n\tag2$$We are dealing with $n$ independent (hence distinct) experiments that can succeed or fail.

The variance of sum $(2)$ equals the sum of variances because the $Y_i$ are independent, and this results in $np(1-p)$.

That is not true for sum $(1)$ where independence lacks and the result is $n^2p(1-p)$.

Comment: Suppose that I now have $k$ pieces of paper, and I know the mean and variance of the continuous distribution of the weights of papers. If I wanted to find the variance of the sum of the weights of the $k$ pieces of paper, would I use the $\sigma^2 = k^2\sigma^2_X$ or $\sigma^2 = k\sigma^2_X$?

Comment: The second if there is independence. If e.g. $k=3$ then the sum of the weights is $X_1+X_2+X_3$ with independent $X_i$ then:$$\mathsf{Var}(X_1+X_2+X_3)=\mathsf{Var}X_1+\mathsf{Var}X_2+\mathsf{Var}X_3=3\sigma^2$$